# Initialising a new Dictionary with a List of keys

Tags: c#, linq, dictionary

I am initialising a new Dictionary and putting each key one by one like so:

```
igData = data.Select(x => new Dictionary<string, string> {
                     ["Date"] = x.GetValueOrDefault("DATE"),
                     ["SP"] = x.GetValueOrDefault("SP"),
                     ["IG"] = x.GetValueOrDefault("IG")}).ToList();
```

This is fine but the rest of the keys need to be headers that I have created in `List<string> headers`

Is it possible to add this list of headers within the initialisation above? Something like this:

```
igData = data.Select(x => new Dictionary<string, string> {
     ["Date"] = x.GetValueOrDefault("DATE"),
     ["SP"] = x.GetValueOrDefault("SP"),
     ["IG"] = x.GetValueOrDefault("IG"),
     headers.Select(y => new KeyValuePair<string, string>
                                             (y, x.GetValueOrDefault["IG"])).ToList();
```

I understand the value is the same but that is intended. Is the above possible or is this something I would have separate. It would be ideal to do it in the above since I have access to the value from the `data` collection.

Comment: What is the type of `data`/`headers`? Why do you create so many dictionaries?

Comment: You should use the `ToDictionary` extension.

Comment: @ChengChen data is a `List<Dictionary<string, string>>` and headers is `List<string>`.

Comment: If you want a list of KeyValuePair<string, string>, then use List<KeyValuePair<string, string>> instead of a dictionary.  You then have an option of using AddRange() to add multiple items at one time where a dictionary only has Add().

Comment: A collection of dictionaries allways make me feel like -uaaah, yeah - uncconfortable. They tend to grow unexpectably and thus become less and less maintanable, in particular when you data-structures become more complex. Instead you should consider to create a class with the properties.

Comment: I don't understand this question. Why doesn't `GetHalfHourlyTimeHeaders()` return `["Date", "SP", "IG"]` etc ?

Comment: @Fabjan Date, SP are predefined names of headers that come from the `data` collection. I need to add my own headers after these (Half hour times).

Comment: @UsmanKhan So you could put them *all* into one collection and then use *ToDictionary* going through them all. It looks like an XY problem to me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cant do it in an initializer like that, but I'd suggest you can do it with a little bit of `Concat` and `ToDictionary`:

```
igData = data.Select(x => {
   return new KeyValuePair<string,string>[]{
          new KeyValuePair<string,string>("Date", x.GetValueOrDefault("DATE")),
          new KeyValuePair<string,string>("SP", x.GetValueOrDefault("SP")),
          new KeyValuePair<string,string>("IG", x.GetValueOrDefault("IG"))
       }.Concat(
          headers.GetHalfHourlyTimeHeaders().Select(y => new KeyValuePair<string, string>
                                             (y, x.GetValueOrDefault["IG"])).ToList()
       ).ToDictionary(k => k.Key, v => v.Value);
});
```

Comment: Is there a reason why you create an array of KVP instead of just initialising a new Dictionary and adding into that? Just trying to understand the code better.

Comment: Not really, just so I could chain (`.Concat`) them with your `GetHalfHourlyTimeHeaders` and create one dictionary.

Comment: Oh okay, so adding straight into a Dictionary would not work with Concat?

Comment: It probably would, A Dictionary is just an `IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<>>` - the question is, is the overhead of another dictionary necessary.

Comment: Okay, that makes sense. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

```
igData = data.Select(x =>
    new Dictionary<string, string>(headers.GetHalfHourlyTimeHeaders().ToDictionary(y => y, y => x.GetValueOrDefault("IG")))
    {
        ["Date"] = x.GetValueOrDefault("DATE"),
        ["SP"] = x.GetValueOrDefault("SP"),
        ["IG"] = x.GetValueOrDefault("IG")
    });
```

Query syntax looks better to me

```
igData = from x in data
         let ig = x.GetValueOrDefault("IG")
         select new Dictionary<string, string>(headers.GetHalfHourlyTimeHeaders().ToDictionary(y => y, y => ig))
         {
             ["Date"] = x.GetValueOrDefault("DATE"),
             ["SP"] = x.GetValueOrDefault("SP"),
             ["IG"] = ig
         };
```

Answer (score 0):

Similar to the answer of Jamiec but in my opinion more readable (but not tested for performance):

```
List<Dictionary<string, string>> igData = data.Select(x => 
    {
        var dict = new Dictionary<string, string>
        {
            ["Date"] = x.GetValueOrDefault("DATE"),
            ["SP"] = x.GetValueOrDefault("SP"),
            ["IG"] = x.GetValueOrDefault("IG")
        };

        // I hope I understand correctly that GetHalfHourlyTimeHeaders returns List<string>
        foreach (string header in headers.GetHalfHourlyTimeHeaders())
        {
            dict.Add(header, x.GetValueOrDefault("IG"));
        }

        return dict;
    }
).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

I like this way:

```
igData =
    data
        .Select(x =>
            Enumerable
                .Concat(
                    headers
                        .GetHalfHourlyTimeHeaders()
                        .Select(k => new { k, v = x.GetValueOrDefault("IG") }),
                    new [] { "Date", "SP", "IG" }
                        .Select(k => new { k, v = x.GetValueOrDefault(k.ToUpper()) }))
                .ToDictionary(z => z.k, z => z.v))
        .ToList();
```

Comment: This doesn't work since it doesn't get the values from the `data` collection.

Comment: @UsmanKhan - Sorry, you're right. I missed that part of query. I've fixed it.